# A trip around the United Kingdom?

Tags: knowledge, geography

Last year, I visited the following towns and cities in the UK, in order, following a specific route

> Huddersfield
>   Portsmouth
>   Grantham
>   Sutton
>   Edinburgh
>   Giffnock
>   London
>   Eastbourne

**Where did I go next?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The next place is

> Manhattan, which explains the question mark in the title.

as this is the

> birthplace of [Boris Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Johnson) the current UK Prime Minister

and the list is

> Huddersfield - [Harold Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Wilson)
>  Portsmouth - [Jim Callaghan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Callaghan)
>  Grantham - [Margaret Thatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Thatcher)
>  Sutton - [John Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Major)
>  Edinburgh - [Tony Blair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Blair)
>  Giffnock - [Gordon Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Brown)
>  London - [David Cameron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cameron)
>  Eastbourne - [Theresa May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresa_May)

Comment: That's it Tom, nicely done.

Comment: How did you figure it out? :O Given that this is basically trivia and not a logic puzzle, I guess there is no tips how to approach these...

Comment: @jnovacho - the Grantham clue rang an alarm bell.

Comment: Looking up a less common clue like Giffnock, to see what's it's famous for, is worth trying.